# How to get LocaleTime without seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

i have a timestamp which is for example '2013-01-21T01:23:44' 
i am doing this to get the time

```
var time1= new Date('2013-01-21T01:23:44');
var time2 = time1.toLocaleTimeString();
```

This is returning the time but as 01:23:44 . How do i do this in a way it does not return the seconds .

Comment: I believe those are seconds.

Comment: yikes . my bad. edited the question

Comment: `s.replace(/:\d\d /, ' ');`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about trimming it off using regex?

```
time2 = time1.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');
```

Comment: *toLocaleTimeString* is implementation dependent and also changes depending on user settings for the system and browser.

Comment: @RobG True. Unfortunately, I don't know if there is good, standardized method that would work in all browsers and for all users.

Comment: The OP shouldn't be using *toLocaleString* for this as it's supposed to be customised for the user independently of the script writer, so it should only be used in that context. If a specific format is required, manual formatting based on generic Date methods should be used.

Answer (score 6):

> This sometimes wont work, see [RobG answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21298305/908879).

remove the last 3 characters:

`str = str.slice(0, -3);`

Comment: -1 Trimms `' AM'` (or `' PM'` depending on your timezone) from the end.

Comment: @RobG he lied then, he said it was returning `01:23:44`, many of us made the answer acording to that, some used split, other used other sorts of string manipulation.

Comment: The OP uses *toLocaleString*, which typically returns am/pm after the time (but not necessarily always, an implementation may take into account a system preference for 24hr time). The OP just wants to trim the seconds from the time part, so an answer should accommondate that. If you edit your answer, the downvote can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

```
> var time1= new Date('2013-01-21T01:23:44');
```

Until ES5, parsing of strings by the Date constructor was entirely implementation dependent. Subsequent to ES5, there are 3 formats that are supported (the formats produced by *Date.prototype.toString*, *toISOString* and *toUTCString*) but everything else is still implementation dependent.

Timestamps in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss without an offset should be parsed as local, but there may be non–conforming implementations in use.

One solution is to parse it to a Date then format the time as required.

The [*localeTimeString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.7) function is implementation dependent and results vary depending on system settings. It's intended to represent a time that is tailored for particular users, so you should not mess with it as you can't be certain of its format (and it's supposed to be something the user will understand, not somethign you *think* they will understand).

The following uses a couple of small functions to parse the timestamp to a Date then format the time as required.

```js
// Parse timestamp in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss format as local
function parseDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/g);
  return new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], 0);
}

// Format time as hh:mm AM/PM
function formatHHMM(date) {
  function z(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
  }
  var h = date.getHours();
  return z(h % 12 || 12) + ':' + z(date.getMinutes()) + ' ' + (h < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
}

console.log(
  formatHHMM(parseDateString('2013-01-21T00:23:44')) // 12:23 AM
);
```

your result may differ, it depends on your timezone as the string is treated as UTC.

Comment: sigh, +1ing someone who -1ed me but this answer is really complete

Comment: noon is not "0". formatHHMM(new Date(2022, 4, 26, 12)); //00:00 PM

Answer (score 3):

You can set the timeStyle to short.

```
var time1 = new Date('2013-01-21T01:23:44');
var time2 = time1.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {timeStyle:'short'}); //1:23 AM
```

Comment: oh Lord. finally nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you would like to work with an additional library but momentjs is awesome for date and time formats. You can find the site here: http://momentjs.com/
You can simply change the format like

```
var time1 = moment().format("hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
  hour: "2-digit",
  hour12: true, // Delete for 24-hour format
  minute: "2-digit"
});
```