# Removing seconds from Live clock using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time, live, seconds, real-time-clock

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the seconds group in a live clock made with JavaScript. Ive been tinkering with it for a while now and have not been successful so far. Any advice or guidance well be gratefully welcomed.

Here's what I'm working with...

```js
function myClock() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const date = new Date();
    const timeOutput = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeOutput;
    myClock();
  }, 1000)
}
myClock();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Just replace the setTimeout delay of 1 second (`}, 1000)`) by a delay of a minute should work:  (`}, 60 * 1000)`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get LocaleTime without seconds in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298035/how-to-get-localetime-without-seconds-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just split your timeOutput and then grab the hour and minutes, like so:

```js
function myClock() {         
    setTimeout(function() {   
      const date = new Date();
      const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {hour12: false});
      const split = dateString.split(":");
      const hour = parseInt(split[0]);
      const min = parseInt(split[1]);
      const period = hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
      const timeOutput = hour + ':' + min + ' ' + period;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeOutput; 
      myClock();
    }, 1000)
}
  
myClock();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. Your solution somehow strips out the AM and PM unit. Anyway on bringing that back?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include AM/PM. It just runs a check on the hour to see if it's less than 12. If it is, set to AM, otherwise set to PM. ```const period = hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';```

Comment: Working perfectly :)